# How do I sub-divide the x-axis in a column range chart to display multiple lines in one tick interval

Tags: charts, highcharts

I started with making a column range high chart for displaying year based events. This initially was suiting my requirements. But with more data moving in it turned out too messy specially when events are closely spaced. Something like below:

[image]

I am now looking for displaying all these events vertically below each other but still categorized together, so that 4-5 red events are displayed vertically at their respective horizontal position and then a bunch of blue events and so on. Basically I am looking for a way to sub-divide my vertical axis (which is called x-axis in column range charts).

I tried looking HighChart column range API [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange)

Based on this link and editing it for my requirements, I have been able to make a chart to demonstrate what I am looking for. Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ytu3e5a2/5/)

But this still is far from what I exactly need

1. First, I have just made a work around to display months vertically. Howeevr I would need a robust way of classifying axis for each month.
2. The events appear on gridlines also, ideally I want all events of one type to be clubbed within two horizontal gridlines.
3. Events for each month can vary from zero to anything. So the grid spacing should adjust accordingly.

May be I am not using exact chart type based on my requirement. But I could not see any other type fitting these requirements.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Copying fiddler code below for future reference:

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {

        chart: {
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted: true
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Events by month'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            tickInterval : 3,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            gridLineColor: '#aaa',
            gridLineOffset : 10,
            labels: {
                            align: 'center',
                            x: -20,
                            y: 30,

                        }
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Events by Month'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },

        plotOptions: {
            columnrange: {
                dataLabels: {
                                format: '{point.name}',
                                enabled: true,
                                align: 'center',
                                color: '#000',
                                inside: true,
                                allowOverlap: true,
                                style: {
                                    textShadow: false,
                                    fontWeight: 'normal'
                                }
                            }
            }
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Events',
            data: [
                    {low :3, high:6.4, name :"Event1", color:'red'},
                {low :0, high:4, name :"Event2",color:'red'},
                {low :1, high:3, name :"Event3",color:'red'},
                {low :2, high:2.4, name :"Event4", color:'green'},
                {low :3, high:5, name :"Event5", color:'green'},
                {low :4, high:7, name :"Event6", color:'green'},
                {low :3, high:6.4, name :"Event7", color:'green'},
                {low :0, high:4, name :"Event8", color:'blue'},
                {low :1, high:3, name :"Event9", color:'blue'},
                {low :2, high:2.4, name :"Event10", color:'blue'},
                {low :3, high:5, name :"Event11", color:'blue'},
                {low :4, high:7, name :"Event12", color:'blue'}
                ]
        }]

    });
```

Comment: THe first point is clear, but I do not understand the other two. A grid line is just a straight line from bottom to top, if your events (different types) have different length, how do you want to plot a straight line to limit the events? Or maybe you want to have a different cube for each event type?

Comment: @morganfree Hope you had a look at the shard fiddle. Basically I am talking of horizontal gridlines here. Between two horizontal gridlines I want all the events (each one of which will be horizontal and vertically below the other one) to not touch the gridline. The fiddle should make it more clear

Comment: Split your data in multiple series - one series per event type. Positioning will be done automatically. http://jsfiddle.net/c951ynLe/

Comment: My requirement are slightly more than this..But anyways your comment still helps. Particulary the distance from gridlines unlike my fiddle. Can you explain the series object of your code. Why the use of arrow function ?